# Array out of bounds error Visual basic forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi im new to this but my code keeps giving me the same error after ive entered three countries and their details. Once i click Ok on my third data entry i get an out of bounds error message.

here is my code if anyone can help

```
Dim countries(2) As employee

    Dim row As Integer

    For row = 0 To 2
        countries(row).CountryName = InputBox("row" & row & " Enter name of country")
        countries(row).population = InputBox("row" & row & " Enter population")
        countries(row).Capital = InputBox("row" & row & " enter capital city")
        countries(row).GDP = InputBox("row" & row & " Enter GDP value ")
        countries(row).worldRanking = InputBox("row" & row & " GDP world rank")
        countries(row).Democracy = InputBox("row" & row & " Democracy based? (1 = yes 2 = no")
    Next row
    For row = 0 To 4

        If countries(row).worldRanking < 100 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(countries(row).CountryName)
        End If

    Next row
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a 3-element array here:

```
Dim countries(2) As employee
```

(2) = 0 to 2 = three elements.

So `countries(row)` where `row` > 2 isn't defined.

Arrays aren't always the best choice for collections. Have a look at `IEnumerable`, `List`, etc which have more flexibility (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GetUpperBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=net-5.0) in your loops, instead of hard-coding a number:

```
For row = 0 To countries.GetUpperBound(0)
```